# Odd JavasScript string replace behavior with $&

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

With the following code:

```
var x = 'foo';
console.log(x.replace(x, "\\$&"));​
```

The output is '\foo', as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/mPKEx/

Why isn't it

```
'\\$&"?
```

I am replacing all of x with "\$&" which is just a plan old string so why is string.replace doing some crazy substitution when the 2nd arg of the function isn't supposed to do anything except get substitued in...

Comment: It's weird that you just happened to choose those characters. From your perspective it might seem like a bug.

Comment: I was replacing something with a very large block of text that happened to have those characters in it, it took me forever to narrow it down to those characters being the cause.

Comment: 25% of my job is tracking down little mysteries like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$& is a special reference in Javascript's string replace. It **points** to the matched string.

```
$$ - Inserts a "$"
$& - Refers to the entire text of the current pattern match. 
$` - Refers to the text to the left of the current pattern match. 
$' - Refers to the text to the right of the current pattern match.
$n or $nn - Where n or nn are decimal digits, inserts the nth parenthesized
            submatch string, provided the first argument was a RegExp object.
```

([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace))

Comment: Arg makes sense,  This was part of a much bigger text string i was replacing and it took forever for me to figure out that those characters were the problem, thanks for the help!

Comment: Better reference: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.5.4.11 , explains other variations of $ syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In your case:

```
var x = 'foo';
console.log(x.replace(x, function() {return '\\$&'}));
```

See the differences: http://jsfiddle.net/mPKEx/10/

You can [specify a function as the second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). The above-mentioned special replacement patterns ($$, $&, $`, $', $n or $nn) do **not** apply in this case.